# I am not able to get the data of an already traversed vertex data. Can anyone help me?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, janusgraph

I am having an edge(say edge) between two vertices(say v1 and v2). And edge direction is from v1 to v2. In my current situation, I have to count the no. of edges are incoming to v2 based on some condition. Now I am able to count the number of edges, but I am not able to retrieve the data of v2.

```
     g.V().hasLabel('V2').has('type','c').as('p').project('v2Data').by(select('p').inE('edge').count().is(gt(5)).valueMap(true))
```

By the above approch, I have got an error

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element
```

The other approach I tried is,

```
     g.V().hasLabel('v2').has('type','c').as('p').project('v2Data').by(select('p').inE('edge').count().is(gt(5)).select('p').valueMap(true))

The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[286724240]->[SelectOneStep(last,p), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), JanusGraphVertexStep(IN,[willingToPlayAt],edge), RangeGlobalStep(0,6), CountGlobalStep, IsStep(gt(5)), SelectOneStep(last,p), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertyMapStep(value)]
```

I have tried this stack overflow answer [fold() approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466453/gremlin-the-provided-traverser-does-not-map-to-a-value-when-using-project)

I want my output as v2data = [{},{}]

reference:
    `g.addV('game').property('id',1).as('1').
       addV('game').property('id',2).as('2').
       addV('game').property('id',3).as('3').
       addV('game').property('id',4).as('4').
       addV('game').property('id',5).as('5').
       addV('game').property('id',6).as('6').
       addV('loc').property('id',p1).as('p1').
       addV('loc').property('id',p2).as('p2').
       addE('edge').from('1').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('2').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('3').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('4').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('5').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('6').to('p1').
       addE('edge').from('1').to('p2').
       addE('edge').from('2').to('p2');`

query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('loc').has('type','c').
  project('locData').
  by(where(inE('edge').count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())
```

Expected output:

```
{locData=[{id=[p1],....}]}
```

because gt(5) is satisfied only for loc with id=p1.

But I am getting my result as

```
{locData=[{id=[p1],....}]}
{locData=[]}(p2 is not satisfied with my condition.)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear what you're trying to do, but that error is easy to explain. you are calling `count()` which is a reducing step that produces a `Long`. You then try to call `valueMap()` on that `Long` which produces an error, since `valueMap()` can only be called on an `Element` (e.g. `Vertex`).

So, if I take your query as is, it should start returning something if you do:

```
g.V().hasLabel('V2').has('type','c').as('p').
  project('v2Data').
    by(select('p').where(inE('edge').count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())
```

You need the `fold()` so that if your condition is not met, you get something returned if your filter returns no values (i.e. `fold()` will reduce to an empty list in that case).

That said, your query still could use some work. First, I don't see the need for "p" because its value is the current traverse in the stream, so:

```
g.V().hasLabel('V2').has('type','c').
  project('v2Data').
    by(where(inE('edge').count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())
```

Then, I prefer combination of the two `has()` steps:

```
g.V().has('V2','type','c').
  project('v2Data').
    by(where(inE('edge').count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())
```

Finally, you don't really need to `count()` all the edges to find out there are more than "5", you just need a max of "6" so maybe:

```
g.V().has('V2','type','c').
  project('v2Data').
    by(where(inE('edge').limit(6).count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())
```

Comment: ,I have tried this approach `g.V().hasLabel('V2').has('type','c').project('v2Data').by(where(inE('edge').count().is(gt(5))).valueMap(true).fold())`. Because of fold() I am getting my output as **==>{v2Data[{id:id1,name:name1}]} ==>{v2Data=[]}==>{v2Data=[]}**

Comment: If my condition is true I am getting some data which is ok. But I don't want to get empty arrays when the condition is failed. So can you suggest something other than fold()?

Comment: well, what do you want instead of an empty array? or do you just not what that vertex represented in the first place? I think that if you want a more exact answer you should edit your question to include sample data as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random and then some expected output.